# Why the variable is being treated like a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this function to be created, but the variable `view_size`is being treated as a column.

I'm getting an error saying that `column view_size don't exists.`

Why?

If I change the context, it works (example: only do a query, is treated like a variable).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_view(view_size INTEGER) RETURNS VOID  
AS $$
BEGIN
    CREATE VIEW token_relation
    AS
    SELECT * FROM textblockhastoken     
    ORDER BY textblockid, sentence, position
    LIMIT view_size;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: variables I suppose must be declared like : declare @view_size int

Comment: That's got nothing to do with variables. The DDL statement `CREATE VIEW` does not take variables. You must feed it a text. That's why @aingram's answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_view(view_size INTEGER) RETURNS VOID  
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW token_relation 
    AS 
    SELECT * FROM textblockhastoken 
    ORDER BY textblockid, sentence, position 
    LIMIT ' || view_size;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```